# make expand all into collapse one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am a beginner in javascript and found it very difficult to enable toggle function where the Expand All and Collapse all are one button

Please can you help me out with this jsfiddle example?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DTxJT/)

```
<div id="sidetreecontrol"><a href="?#">Collapse All</a> | <a href="?#">Expand All</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a third link in `#sidetreecontrol` to get a "Toggle" control:

```
<div id="sidetreecontrol">
    <a href="#">Collapse All</a>
    |
    <a href="#">Expand All</a>
    |
    <a href="#">Toggle All</a>
</div>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DTxJT/1/**

If you don't want the `Collapse All` and `Expand All` links, hide them with CSS:

```
<div id="sidetreecontrol">
    <a href="#" class="hidden">Collapse All</a>
    <a href="#" class="hidden">Expand All</a>
    <a href="#">Toggle All</a>
</div>
```

where:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DTxJT/2/**

I couldn't find the options documentation for the [plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) you're using, otherwise I'd link to it.